Wifi card only works after Ethernet is connected but stays working when cable is disconnected
Im having a strange problem with my AC 9260 wifi-card. Its hardblocked in rfkill untill I connect ethernet for a brief second and then its unblocked untill I reboot the system. To clarify i only have the cable connected for a second then I unplug it and the network still works until reboot. I have tried different firmwares, other debian distros and so on and now im at a loss of what to do. Please tell me if you want to see any other logs. I also have a video of me pluging in the cable and getting wifi but it doesent really say aything else that what I have described.
Additional info

Its baremetal
PC is Thinkpad e11 7th gen m3
The system is properly updated

lspci and dmesg logs:
$ lspci
    Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 5(802.11ac) Wireless-AC 9x6x [Thunder Peak] (rev 29)
            Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wi-Fi 5 Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz 2x2
            Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
            Memory at f1c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
            Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
            Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
            Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
            Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
            Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
            Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
            Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
            Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
            Kernel modules: iwlwifi

$ sudo dmesg |grep wifi
[    3.397039] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.405963] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x2816, cnv-id 0x1000200 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    3.406074] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: PCI dev 2526/0014, rev=0x321, rfid=0x105110
[    3.423079] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 28
[    3.423686] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 46.7e3e4b69.0 9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.344048] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz, REV=0x321
[    4.353047] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[    4.402303] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 0c:54:15:67:ba:29, OTP minor version: 0x4
[    4.482472] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   88.593062] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[   88.593071] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio enabled)
[   88.828381] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0

As you can se in the bottom of dmesg after ethernet is connected at 88s the radio is enabled again.

Full dmesg after the first two secounds have passed
[    2.056727] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    2.118425] systemd[1]: systemd 255.4-1ubuntu8 running in system mode (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT -GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY +P11KIT +QRENCODE +TPM2 +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -BPF_FRAMEWORK -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified)
[    2.118457] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[    2.119792] systemd[1]: Hostname set to <sidetrakinator>.
[    2.294811] systemd[1]: Queued start job for default target graphical.target.
[    2.311804] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice - Slice /system/modprobe.
[    2.312305] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice - Slice /system/systemd-fsck.
[    2.312603] systemd[1]: Created slice user.slice - User and Session Slice.
[    2.312696] systemd[1]: Started systemd-ask-password-wall.path - Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    2.312937] systemd[1]: Set up automount proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount - Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    2.312966] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FB32\x2dEB64.device - /dev/disk/by-uuid/FB32-EB64...
[    2.312997] systemd[1]: Reached target integritysetup.target - Local Integrity Protected Volumes.
[    2.313029] systemd[1]: Reached target nss-user-lookup.target - User and Group Name Lookups.
[    2.313047] systemd[1]: Reached target remote-fs.target - Remote File Systems.
[    2.313060] systemd[1]: Reached target slices.target - Slice Units.
[    2.313081] systemd[1]: Reached target snapd.mounts-pre.target - Mounting snaps.
[    2.313123] systemd[1]: Reached target veritysetup.target - Local Verity Protected Volumes.
[    2.313264] systemd[1]: Listening on dm-event.socket - Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[    2.313419] systemd[1]: Listening on lvm2-lvmpolld.socket - LVM2 poll daemon socket.
[    2.313665] systemd[1]: Listening on syslog.socket - Syslog Socket.
[    2.313797] systemd[1]: Listening on systemd-fsckd.socket - fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    2.313871] systemd[1]: Listening on systemd-initctl.socket - initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    2.314010] systemd[1]: Listening on systemd-journald-dev-log.socket - Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    2.314194] systemd[1]: Listening on systemd-journald.socket - Journal Socket.
[    2.314251] systemd[1]: systemd-pcrextend.socket - TPM2 PCR Extension (Varlink) was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionSecurity=measured-uki).
[    2.314630] systemd[1]: Listening on systemd-udevd-control.socket - udev Control Socket.
[    2.314777] systemd[1]: Listening on systemd-udevd-kernel.socket - udev Kernel Socket.
[    2.316175] systemd[1]: Mounting dev-hugepages.mount - Huge Pages File System...
[    2.317030] systemd[1]: Mounting dev-mqueue.mount - POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    2.318509] systemd[1]: Mounting sys-kernel-debug.mount - Kernel Debug File System...
[    2.321102] systemd[1]: Mounting sys-kernel-tracing.mount - Kernel Trace File System...
[    2.321393] systemd[1]: Finished blk-availability.service - Availability of block devices.
[    2.328376] systemd[1]: Starting keyboard-setup.service - Set the console keyboard layout...
[    2.331331] systemd[1]: Starting kmod-static-nodes.service - Create List of Static Device Nodes...
[    2.332361] systemd[1]: Starting lvm2-monitor.service - Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling...
[    2.334933] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@configfs.service - Load Kernel Module configfs...
[    2.336759] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod...
[    2.340366] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm...
[    2.343351] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@efi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore...
[    2.347430] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@fuse.service - Load Kernel Module fuse...
[    2.351595] systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop...
[    2.351946] systemd[1]: systemd-fsck-root.service - File System Check on Root Device was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=!/run/initramfs/fsck-root).
[    2.360733] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-journald.service - Journal Service...
[    2.364203] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules...
[    2.364248] systemd[1]: systemd-pcrmachine.service - TPM2 PCR Machine ID Measurement was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionSecurity=measured-uki).
[    2.365310] pstore: Using crash dump compression: deflate
[    2.385059] pstore: Registered efi_pstore as persistent store backend
[    2.391375] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-remount-fs.service - Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[    2.391501] systemd[1]: systemd-tpm2-setup-early.service - TPM2 SRK Setup (Early) was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionSecurity=measured-uki).
[    2.393387] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-udev-trigger.service - Coldplug All udev Devices...
[    2.399308] systemd[1]: Mounted dev-hugepages.mount - Huge Pages File System.
[    2.400433] systemd[1]: Mounted dev-mqueue.mount - POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    2.400719] systemd[1]: Mounted sys-kernel-debug.mount - Kernel Debug File System.
[    2.400980] systemd[1]: Mounted sys-kernel-tracing.mount - Kernel Trace File System.
[    2.401494] systemd[1]: Finished kmod-static-nodes.service - Create List of Static Device Nodes.
[    2.402642] systemd[1]: modprobe@configfs.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.404149] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@configfs.service - Load Kernel Module configfs.
[    2.404709] systemd[1]: modprobe@dm_mod.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.404957] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod.
[    2.406522] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.407190] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm.
[    2.407738] systemd[1]: modprobe@efi_pstore.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.408058] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@efi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
[    2.408600] systemd[1]: modprobe@fuse.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.414466] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@fuse.service - Load Kernel Module fuse.
[    2.415081] systemd[1]: modprobe@loop.service: Deactivated successfully.
[    2.415962] systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop.
[    2.417600] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): re-mounted 98b73487-2564-4866-bef9-298158459bb2 r/w. Quota mode: none.
[    2.418409] systemd-journald[304]: Collecting audit messages is disabled.
[    2.420281] systemd[1]: Mounting sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount - FUSE Control File System...
[    2.421680] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    2.422252] systemd[1]: Mounting sys-kernel-config.mount - Kernel Configuration File System...
[    2.422337] systemd[1]: systemd-repart.service - Repartition Root Disk was skipped because no trigger condition checks were met.
[    2.425748] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service - Create Static Device Nodes in /dev gracefully...
[    2.430534] systemd[1]: Finished lvm2-monitor.service - Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
[    2.436463] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    2.437993] systemd[1]: Finished systemd-remount-fs.service - Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[    2.438389] systemd[1]: Mounted sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount - FUSE Control File System.
[    2.440891] systemd[1]: Activating swap swapfile.swap - /swapfile...
[    2.441413] systemd[1]: systemd-hwdb-update.service - Rebuild Hardware Database was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionNeedsUpdate=/etc).
[    2.441479] systemd[1]: systemd-pstore.service - Platform Persistent Storage Archival was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=/sys/fs/pstore).
[    2.451079] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-random-seed.service - Load/Save OS Random Seed...
[    2.451143] systemd[1]: systemd-tpm2-setup.service - TPM2 SRK Setup was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionSecurity=measured-uki).
[    2.452945] systemd[1]: Mounted sys-kernel-config.mount - Kernel Configuration File System.
[    2.464843] Adding 524284k swap on /swapfile.  Priority:-2 extents:5 across:786432k SS
[    2.467962] systemd[1]: Activated swap swapfile.swap - /swapfile.
[    2.468668] systemd[1]: Finished systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules.
[    2.469166] systemd[1]: Reached target swap.target - Swaps.
[    2.482438] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables...
[    2.484146] systemd[1]: Finished systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service - Create Static Device Nodes in /dev gracefully.
[    2.484631] systemd[1]: Finished systemd-random-seed.service - Load/Save OS Random Seed.
[    2.485294] systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service - Create System Users was skipped because no trigger condition checks were met.
[    2.487738] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service - Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[    2.513469] systemd[1]: Finished systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables.
[    2.514171] systemd[1]: Finished systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service - Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[    2.524317] systemd[1]: Starting systemd-udevd.service - Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files...
[    2.524748] systemd[1]: Finished keyboard-setup.service - Set the console keyboard layout.
[    2.525086] systemd[1]: Reached target local-fs-pre.target - Preparation for Local File Systems.
[    2.530245] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-bare-5.mount - Mount unit for bare, revision 5...
[    2.531920] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-core22-1380.mount - Mount unit for core22, revision 1380...
[    2.538545] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-firefox-4173.mount - Mount unit for firefox, revision 4173...
[    2.543180] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-firmware\x2dupdater-127.mount - Mount unit for firmware-updater, revision 127...
[    2.550323] loop0: detected capacity change from 0 to 552192
[    2.551080] loop1: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
[    2.552721] loop2: detected capacity change from 0 to 152040
[    2.554193] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-176.mount - Mount unit for gnome-42-2204, revision 176...
[    2.558189] loop3: detected capacity change from 0 to 21952
[    2.559283] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount - Mount unit for gtk-common-themes, revision 1535...
[    2.567836] loop4: detected capacity change from 0 to 1034424
[    2.568346] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-snapd-21465.mount - Mount unit for snapd, revision 21465...
[    2.569880] systemd[1]: Mounting snap-thunderbird-470.mount - Mount unit for thunderbird, revision 470...
[    2.572548] loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 187776
[    2.587442] systemd[1]: Mounting tmp.mount - /tmp...
[    2.592457] loop6: detected capacity change from 0 to 79328
[    2.593350] systemd[1]: Mounting var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount - Mount unit for firefox, revision 4173 via mount-control...
[    2.593452] loop7: detected capacity change from 0 to 281176
[    2.608255] systemd[1]: Started systemd-journald.service - Journal Service.
[    2.664548] systemd-journald[304]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[    2.667472] systemd-journald[304]: File /var/log/journal/4df84ea1b15b4015b44fa589f60812ca/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[    3.080711] Consider using thermal netlink events interface
[    3.127799] intel_pmc_core INT33A1:00:  initialized
[    3.192077] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
[    3.316291] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    3.317156] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    3.317594] Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    3.317915] Loaded X.509 cert 'wens: 61c038651aabdcf94bd0ac7ff06c7248db18c600'
[    3.368306] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 5 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer
[    3.368313] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules
[    3.368315] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules
[    3.368317] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-14 Joules
[    3.368319] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules
[    3.368321] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain psys 2^-14 Joules
[    3.368957] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    3.371000] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SPD Write Disable is set
[    3.371026] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus using PCI interrupt
[    3.373864] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    3.381439] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    3.391234] i2c i2c-2: 2/2 memory slots populated (from DMI)
[    3.397039] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.405963] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x2816, cnv-id 0x1000200 wfpm id 0x80000000
[    3.406074] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: PCI dev 2526/0014, rev=0x321, rfid=0x105110
[    3.423018] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 0
[    3.423028] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 1
[    3.423032] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 2
[    3.423036] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 3
[    3.423039] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 4
[    3.423042] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 6
[    3.423045] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 8
[    3.423049] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 9
[    3.423052] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 10
[    3.423055] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 11
[    3.423059] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 15
[    3.423062] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 16
[    3.423065] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 18
[    3.423069] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 19
[    3.423072] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 20
[    3.423075] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 21
[    3.423079] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: WRT: Overriding region id 28
[    3.423686] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 46.7e3e4b69.0 9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.454852] proc_thermal 0000:00:04.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.460398] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    3.460404] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[    3.664953] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    3.664960] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    3.664962] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    3.664965] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[    3.664967] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain psys
[    3.668250] usb 1-5: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b604)
[    3.682796] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.057734] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x4f3001)
[    4.068539] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x10, 0x18, 0x0d.
[    4.079051] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan sample query result 00, 1f, 86
[    4.089901] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan ic body: 0x10, current fw version: 0x3
[    4.110425] psmouse serio1: elantech: Trying to set up SMBus access
[    4.328423] intel_tcc_cooling: Programmable TCC Offset detected
[    4.328903] elan_i2c 2-0015: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    4.336547] elan_i2c 2-0015: unexpected iap version 0x00 (ic type: 0x1f), firmware update will not work
[    4.336559] elan_i2c 2-0015: Elan Touchpad: Module ID: 0x001f, Firmware: 0x0001, Sample: 0x0000, IAP: 0x0000
[    4.337309] input: Elan Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.4/i2c-2/2-0015/input/input9
[    4.344048] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz, REV=0x321
[    4.345361] thermal thermal_zone4: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[    4.347872] i915 0000:00:02.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    4.353047] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[    4.378279] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    4.402303] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 0c:54:15:67:ba:29, OTP minor version: 0x4
[    4.425035] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=mem
[    4.425447] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    4.426674] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    4.430254] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576795.277:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name=4D6F6E676F444220436F6D70617373 pid=532 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.432116] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576795.278:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="QtWebEngineProcess" pid=533 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.432130] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576795.278:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="1password" pid=530 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.432459] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576795.279:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="Discord" pid=531 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.433562] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_ops [i915])
[    4.435663] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576795.282:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="brave" pid=540 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.437802] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576795.284:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="busybox" pid=542 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.439438] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576795.286:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="buildah" pid=541 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.441490] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576795.288:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="cam" pid=543 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.445013] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576795.291:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ch-checkns" pid=547 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.480806] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:102:DDI B/PHY B] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[    4.480816] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:118:DDI C/PHY C] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[    4.482472] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.323577] kauditd_printk_skb: 122 callbacks suppressed
[    5.323581] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576796.170:133): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="rsyslogd" pid=785 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.494031] loop8: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
[    5.558350] NET: Registered PF_QIPCRTR protocol family
[    5.627374] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20230929 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 1
[    5.632613] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    5.633323] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input10
[    5.633651] i915 display info: display version: 9
[    5.633656] i915 display info: cursor_needs_physical: no
[    5.633659] i915 display info: has_cdclk_crawl: no
[    5.633662] i915 display info: has_cdclk_squash: no
[    5.633664] i915 display info: has_ddi: yes
[    5.633667] i915 display info: has_dp_mst: yes
[    5.633669] i915 display info: has_dsb: no
[    5.633672] i915 display info: has_fpga_dbg: yes
[    5.633674] i915 display info: has_gmch: no
[    5.633676] i915 display info: has_hotplug: yes
[    5.633679] i915 display info: has_hti: no
[    5.633681] i915 display info: has_ipc: yes
[    5.633683] i915 display info: has_overlay: no
[    5.633686] i915 display info: has_psr: yes
[    5.633688] i915 display info: has_psr_hw_tracking: yes
[    5.633691] i915 display info: overlay_needs_physical: no
[    5.633693] i915 display info: supports_tv: no
[    5.633696] i915 display info: has_hdcp: yes
[    5.633698] i915 display info: has_dmc: yes
[    5.633700] i915 display info: has_dsc: no
[    5.633770] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.698742] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    5.698747] fbcon: Deferring console take-over
[    5.698753] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    5.718396] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576796.565:134): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=920 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.721012] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC257: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    5.721022] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.721028] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    5.721032] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    5.721036] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    5.721039] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    5.721043] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    5.728310] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576796.575:135): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=920 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    5.812711] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input11
[    5.812860] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input12
[    5.813296] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input13
[    5.819040] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
[    5.819259] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
[    6.638672] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-300:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-300:00, irq=MAC)
[    6.769373] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[    6.955893] audit: type=1400 audit(1718576797.802:136): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1089 comm="cupsd" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[   17.667527] systemd-journald[304]: File /var/log/journal/4df84ea1b15b4015b44fa589f60812ca/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   20.046668] warning: `kded5' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
[   88.498886] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   88.593062] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[   88.593071] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio enabled)
[   88.828381] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0
[   92.366411] wlp2s0: authenticate with f8:32:e4:78:f8:94 (local address=0c:54:15:67:ba:29)
[   92.367504] wlp2s0: send auth to f8:32:e4:78:f8:94 (try 1/3)
[   92.409192] wlp2s0: authenticated
[   92.410712] wlp2s0: associate with f8:32:e4:78:f8:94 (try 1/3)
[   92.414204] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from f8:32:e4:78:f8:94 (capab=0x511 status=0 aid=63)
[   92.417481] wlp2s0: associated
[   95.379370] systemd-journald[304]: Time jumped backwards, rotating.
[  183.097036] workqueue: delayed_fput hogged CPU for >13333us 4 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND

Look at 1.325456 to see that the keyboard toggle for wifi is turned on

Thanks for the help in advance
